# How do I draw things differently depending on the case in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, draw

I have a `StatBarView` class that holds a `Stat`, an `int` named percentage and two `Color`s. In the `Update()` method I smoothly change around the percentage value of the bar, how full it has to be. Next up I have four `Draw()` methods, one for drawing the bar small, one for medium, one for large, and one for drawing it as text instead of graphically.

It works, but.. I feel like this will become a mess if I want to implement more drawing cases.

I could turn the 'text view' into it's own `StatTextView`, but that only moves the problem elsewhere. I also want to avoid having to pass along all kinds of parameters to the draw method, it would make me run all over the place if I want to change the sizes of a few things. I'd also like to avoid some massive method using switch statements, that feels even worse.

I considered passing along an `IStatBarContext` that has a `Draw(int percentage)`, which would work, but feels very complicated. 
Would I have to call `Stat.Draw(spriteBatch, position, new StatBarLarge())` on every iteration of `Draw()`? That's a load of useless new objects per second. Besides, `new StatBarString()` would make no use of that percentage stat. I think I went wrong with my design somewhere.

That said, I don't know how to actually -do- make this code cleaner. Would someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your last example/choice is spot on. It even has a name, the **Strategy** pattern.

In the class based version of this pattern, you would normally just pass in a `new` object every time (as in your example) but because this is in the `Draw` method, I would just have a sample of each strategy stored in your class and pass the existing reference.

Another way to implement this pattern is by using delegates. To do so you would have the `Draw` method take a delegate with the information you need. Something like:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector3 position, Action<int> drawStrategy)
{
   ...
   drawStrategy(percentage);
}
```

You would then pass the function for large, small, text, etc. to this function. `Action<int>` was just an example of course, you can have it return values or take additional parameters as needed.

If the text-version doesn't use percentage, that *is* a code-smell, but you may not need to worry about it to much. **Strategy** is definitely the way to go here.